# How to sum two results in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new at this and I got stuck.

I want to sum the two results that I get with this code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('label').click(function() {
    var total = 0;

    $('.option:checked').each(function() {
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
      $(this).parent().css('background', 'gold');
    });

    $('.option:not(:checked)').each(function() {
      $(this).parent().css('background', '#fff');
    });

    $('#total').html(total + ' $');
  });
});

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

  if (x == 5 || x == 6 || x == 7) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 97 * x;

  } else if (x == 8 || x == 9 || x == 10) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 87 * x;

  } else if (x >= 11) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 82 * x
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="myNumber">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Sum</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<br>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="200" /> Name</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="300" /> Blah</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="400" /> XYZ</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="800" /> Something</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="1200" /> Item</label><br />
<br><br> Total :
<div id="total">0 $</div>
<br>
```

My question is - how to sum the two results and display it in 'Total:' at the end.
And how to remove the 'Sum' button, so you can see the result from the textbox in realtime in 'Total:' ?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Edit : I need the sum from text box and the checkbox. For example : if the user have entered '5' this number equals 5 * 97 = 485. So '5' + Name(200) should be equals to 685.

Comment: You mean the sum from text box and the checkbox?

Comment: Yes, @Krishna Prashatt . That is what i need.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: @Sandesh Gupta , i am still trying to make 'Mr. Polywhirl' code work for me, it's very close to what i need. The switch-case calculations are wrong, when i enter 5 it multiplies to 82, not to 97 like it should be. Maybe i will try to replace the switch-case with if-else construction.

Comment: @SheldonCooper I have added an answer. Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I have defined a new method to calculate total amount. Whenever the `checkbox` or `textbox` is changed, the total is updated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 0;
  $('label').click(function() {
    $('.option:checked').each(function() {
      $(this).parent().css('background', 'gold');
    });

    $('.option:not(:checked)').each(function() {
      $(this).parent().css('background', '#fff');
    });
    
    updateTotal();
  });
});

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  
  if (x == 5 || x == 6 || x == 7) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 97 * x;

  } else if (x == 8 || x == 9 || x == 10) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 87 * x;

  } else if (x >= 11) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 82 * x
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 0;
  };
  
  updateTotal();
}

function updateTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    var totalAmount = 0;
    $('.option:checked').each(function() {
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    
    totalAmount = total + parseInt(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML);
    
    $('#total').html( totalAmount +' $');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="myNumber" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<p id="demo"></p>
<br>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="200" /> Name</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="300" /> Blah</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="400" /> XYZ</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="800" /> Something</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="1200" /> Item</label><br />
<br><br> Total :
<div id="total">0 $</div>
<br>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Sandesh Gupta ! This works perfectly ! Best regards, Sheldon :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new element with ID totalHolder and inside both functions call a third function (e.g. `showTotal()`) to sum those values:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('label').click(function() {
    var total = 0;

    $('.option:checked').each(function() {
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
      $(this).parent().css('background', 'gold');
    });

    $('.option:not(:checked)').each(function() {
      $(this).parent().css('background', '#fff');
    });

    $('#total').html(total + ' $');

    showTotal();
  });
});

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

  if (x == 5 || x == 6 || x == 7) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 97 * x;

  } else if (x == 8 || x == 9 || x == 10) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 87 * x;

  } else if (x >= 11) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 82 * x
  };

   showTotal();
}

function showTotal(){
 var result1= parseInt($('#total').html());
 var result2= parseInt($('#demo').html());

  $("#totalHolder").html(result1+result2);
}
```

In order to remove onClick from button, you just need to set a listener:

```
$(docuemnt).ready(function(){
   $("#myNumber").change(function(){ 
       //Call your function inside the listener
       myFunction() 
    })
})
```

Comment: I can't make this to work. I know the problem is in me. I make my code with video tutorials and a lot of reading online, but its not enough to make it work the way i want to.Basically its my second day of learning about java and html. Thanks again to everyone, have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this satisfies your issue, but you need to do a couple things.

1. You should wrap input fields within a form.
2. Why are you mixing vanilla JS and jQuery? Stick with one or the other.
3. You should not be afraid to modularize your application with various functions.
4. Move the element queries out of the processing functions, instead pass their values in.
5. You can toggle the class in one loop, see below.

```js
/* jQuery plugins */
(function($) {
  /** Checks-off one or more checkboxes in a list of elements. */
  $.fn.check = function(checked) {
    return this.each(function(index, item) {
      if (checked) {
        $(item).prop('checked', 'checked');
      } else {
        $(item).removeProp('checked');
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myNumber').val(5);                // Set value to 5.
  $('.option').slice(0, 1).check(true); // Check the first checkbox.
  $('label').on('click', handleUpdate); // Attach a 'click' listener for label

  handleUpdate();                       // Call the function.
});

function handleUpdate() {
  var sum = sumValues();
  var num = $('#myNumber').val();
  var mult = getMultiplier(num);
  var total = num * mult + sum;

  $('#total').html(total.toFixed(2) + ' $');
  $('#demo').html(mult);
}

function sumValues() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.option').each(function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if (isChecked) total += parseInt($(this).val());
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('checked', isChecked);
  });
  return total;
}

function getMultiplier(value) {
  if (value < 5) {
    return value;
  }
  switch (value) {
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
      return 97;
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
      return 87;
    default:
      return 82;
  }
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
.checked {
  background : gold !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="check-form">
  <input type="number" id="myNumber">
  <button onclick="handleUpdate(); return false;">Sum</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="200" /> Name</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="300" /> Blah</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="400" /> XYZ</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="800" /> Something</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="1200" /> Item</label>
</form>
<br>Total :
<div id="total">0 $</div>
```

Comment: I need the sum from text box and the checkbox. For example : if the user have entered '5' this number equals 5 * 97 = 485. So '5' + Name should be equals to 685.

Comment: @SheldonCooper I updated the code above, I added a jQuery plugin to check off one or more select boxes.